# Connecting two external monitors stopped working in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, laptop, thinkpad

Until a few weeks ago, I was using Ubuntu on my laptop with 2 external monitors, one connected with VGA, the other with mini-DVI (Ubuntu 18.10 on a Thinkpad X250).

After an automatic Ubuntu update a few weeks back, this configuration stopped working. Now I can only connect one of two monitors. They both still function, but only one at a time. If I connect both, the one connected with VGA takes precedence over the one connected with mini-DVI. I only ever see two monitors (the laptop's and one of the two external ones) in the 'Screen Display' settings dialog. Before, there used to be three monitors listed there. If I run `xrandr --listmonitors`, only two monitors show up.

Any obvious reasons for this issue (a change in Ubuntu, gnome, ...)? Any suggestions for how to get it working again?

Thanks.